Windows 11 won’t open any programmes soon after login
I recently switched from a faulty i14900k to AMD 7800x3d, replacing the motherboard of course. I didn’t want to get into issues with Intel/AMD driver incompatibility etc. so I used a USB with windows installation media to format the SSD and install a clean copy of Windows. Everything seems to work OK and initially on logging in everything works fine, for about 30 seconds. After this, no programmes open. The start menu opens and I can open the run prompt and type, but nothing else opens, not even the command prompt. There is nothing else installed on the computer, not even updated drivers. I thought it was due to a Windows update issue (the first time it happened I had been able to install updates) but I went back and started again, this time I installed nothing, not even WiFi drivers, no updates, nothing, a completely blank copy of Windows 11. BIOS is up to date. I have searched online and I have found nothing about this problem, except things that suggest going into settings/command prompt etc. neither of which I can do. I did start in recovery mode and use scannow, it didn’t fix the issue. I also checked the SSD through the command prompt and no issues were found. RAM is brand new. Any ideas?
Update:
It seems the Steam app is the culprit. I installed every update one at a time, no issues, every driver update one at a time, no issues. The only thing I hadn’t installed was the Steam app, I did that but disabled it to launch on start. Restarted, everything worked, opened Steam app, issue recurred. If I don’t open Steam everything works.
So now I have a PC that works but a load of games I can’t use. Any suggestions?

Check that the PC itself is working: boot an OS directly from USB without installing it, such as Linux (e.g., Ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), or Hiren's BootCD PE (https://www.hirensbootcd.org). If that works, then concentrate on the SSD or reinstalling Windows. However, if that cannot boot and run for some time, there are likely hardware issues.
